# Feed an unseen example to a pre-trained model made in Keras

Tags: keras

I've implemented a neural network using Keras. Once trained and tested for final test accuracy, using a matrix with a bunch of rows containing features (plus corresponding labels), I have a model which I should be able to use for prediction.

How can I feed a single unseen example, meaning a feature vector to the model, to obtain a class prediction?

I've looked at their documentation [here](https://keras.io/models/model/) but could not find a method for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the predict method, it takes a batch of input samples and produces predictions, which are the outputs computer by your network. To feed a single example you can just put it inside a numpy ndarray wrapper.